# inconsistent local push notification behavior in android14(oneui 6)

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification

Recently in my react native workout app, some android users are not receiving push notifications when the app is in the background. My app is set to send scheduled push notifications when a rest timer expires while the app is in the background.

By running tests in my device(Galaxy Note 21 Ultra, oneui 6 ) I have found out sometimes the push notification works fine, but sometimes the notifications dont arrive or arrive later than the scheduled time.

I have found out some clues but have not been able to find a reason for the problem.

Here are the information I have about the issue:

- using react-native-push-notification's localNotificationSchedule API to schedule notifications ( this API seems to be using Android's AlarmManager class )
- seems to be happening to users using Samsung Galaxy models + oneui 6
- when a notification doesnt arrive on schedule and I open the app by pressing the app icon, the notification arrives.
- when a notification doesnt arrive on schedule while I am in the home screen, when I turn the screen of the notification arrives.

I tried to find out why this happens but failed..sometimes notifications arrive fine but sometimes they dont.

Is there anything I should be looking for to solve this problem? What could I be missing? Please help me... Thank you so much.

Comment: One of the most common reasons is the power-saving features of these devices. Samsung devices have a feature called "App Power Saving" which can restrict background processes, including push notificationsIf the "App Power Saving" feature is not the issue, you can try using a different push notification library that supports background execution better. One such library is "react-native-firebase" which provides better support for background tasks.

Comment: @PratikPrakashBindage I tested with App Power Saving like you said and found out that if I put my app not to save power, push notifications seem to work as intended. Youre a life saver thank you so much!!!

Comment: i need to put my comment answer to the main answer. if somebody stuck like you . it will help for them to get out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the most common reasons is the power-saving features of these devices. Samsung devices have a feature called "App Power Saving" which can restrict background processes, including push notificationsIf the "App Power Saving" feature is not the issue, you can try using a different push notification library that supports background execution better. One such library is "react-native-firebase" which provides better support for background tasks.

Comment: App Power Saving was indeed the problem. Managed to get push notification working by setting  the app's Battery settings to 'Unrestricted' from 'Optimized'.

Thank you again for your help :)